# Regression with Mixed Factorial Design Experiment

Tags: regression, anova, mediation

I have a 2 x 2 mixed factorial design experiment. I already conducted ANOVA. However, I need to make a final mediation analysis. I will apply Baron and Kenny's steps. So, I need to conduct a regression analysis as well.  It seems like I cannot do it with ANOVA. How can I make a regression analysis for an experiment that has both within and between groups design (mixed factorial model)? Which sources should I be looking at? It is a part of my thesis which I need to send to the professor in a few days. Your help would be much appreciated. You can save a student's life.